# Company is using me System Analyst and Database Administrator, but I signed up here for development

Tags: professionalism

At first I signed into this company because job title is developer. Actually it just want some one who can be SA and DBA in one. Since right now I am reading legacy PHP code and it is very poor. Also database is naming with local language not only the database name, but also variables, and even worst join usually join by text not `FK` or RDBMS relation!

And I am forced to copy out the content of them and make an endpoint which is using PLPGSQL not an ORM or Django based like I signed up for.

I myself choose Django and Flutter. Since I can deliver project alone by myself backend and frontend. And I have no interest in studying any other programming language. I prefer using time finding new project to get more money.

**Problem**

I always got fun question like
"when do you finish this?"
And trickster manager will repeat "you know how to do this, aren't you?"
I know the way to finish, but I don't know where is the data
"You are manager rank. You MUST say you can"

**Questions**

How to politely tell them that they I am not signed for this task?

PS. I have searched several QS in `SE workplace`, but I don't found exact one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can one resign from a new job gracefully?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/how-can-one-resign-from-a-new-job-gracefully)

Comment: Similar to this https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/135553/got-moved-to-a-different-position-from-what-i-signed-up-for-is-it-too-late-to-r

Comment: What is "SA"? And while you're at it, also expand or explain DBA. Not everyone is familiar with such acronyms.

Comment: Thank you very much for all attentions. I feel relief and be prepared for any outcomes

Comment: Who says *You are manager rank. You MUST say you can"*?. Are you expected to know or do you expect your manager to know? You need to communcate better.

Comment: @Sam thanks for removing the abbreviation.   This is a great question, but, unfortunately as it were, it has already been asked many many times!

Comment: @Fattie I understand. Frustration reduced my patient therefore I haven't spent time searching for it. I feel better when I know that this is classic question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like there's a pretty serious disconnect between what you want/expected the job to be and what they actually *expect* you to do in the role. Now assuming that this wasn't discussed at the interview stage then it's on them - they might not have intended to pull a bait and switch but essentially the outcome is the same.

If you're unwilling to do the duties they want you to do and they aren't willing or able to provide you with ones that you find acceptable then this job isn't going to work out for either party. So it might be time to have that uncomfortable conversation about what the reality of the job is going to be going forward. It might be that they are able to commit to the current scenario being temporary - if so I strongly advise you to get some reasonably firm timescales planned out for that and documented - it's okay to allow some flexibility but you don't want to get strung along indefinitely.

If they aren't willing to do that or they aren't especially convincing to you that it will happen then you a going to better off pulling the pin sooner rather than later. Now depending on your personal situation and local job market you would probably be advised to secure something else first before you resign, even if that means stringing the company along for a while and doing what they want you to do.